# How to Edit Header Content of a Custom Theme on Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

Please could someone help me out!

I want to edit the header content to either remove or hide the following sections:

-Compare
-The Store Switcher (ELLYANA STORE)
-The Language Selector (ELLYANA_EN ENGLISH)

I use a custom theme: Fastest Magento 2 Theme.

Thank you.

[image: Relevant Screenshot]

Comment: Please check my ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest_grocery_gourmet/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/> // To remove store language 
    <referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true"/> // To remove store switcher 
</body>
```

For the **compare link**, go to `Stores>configuration> theme options> Product compare > Show compare page link in TopLinks area > No`

[Codazon doc](http://www.codazon.com/document/fastest/magento2/#theme-options)

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly, although for the compare link I had to go to Codazon>fastest options>theme options> Product compare > Show compare page link in TopLinks area > No

Comment: The Store Switcher and Language Selector is still visible in the mobile version of the site how do I remove from there too? Thank you.

Comment: About the mobile, it depends to your theme developpement, you have to find the 2nd block that display it for the mobile then, you remove it, it's is not a Magento standard, you can accept the answer if it helped you. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can update your custom theme's header panel from below path.

Go to your `Custom theme >> Magento_Theme >> Layout >> default.xml` from here you can move block or remove block from header, check below code for your reference.

**/[magento-root-directory]/app/design/frontend/[your-custom-theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
   <body>
        ...
        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" before="logo"/>
        <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="catalog.topnav" />
        <move element="minicart" destination="header.links" />
        <move element="store_language" destination="header.links" before="-" />
        <move element="store.settings.currency" destination="header.links" after="store_language" />
        <move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
        ......
        <referenceBlock name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links" remove="true"/>
        ...
    </body>
```

Please try this and let me know if any issue.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very very helpful, I used Prince's answer it was very pin point. Thanks I am grateful for your response to my question.